# How to convert JSON time into readable human format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time-format

I'm getting data from an api call with ajax. It works fine. I'm just wondering how do I format the `distance_time` so that it is more readable and more user friendly? I've looked into the docs and can't seem to find something to make a quick conversion. Any suggestion?

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://exampleapi.com/key=my_key',
dataType: 'json',
type: 'GET',
contentType:'json',
success: function(data)
{
//console.log( data)

//get distance in miles
var distance_miles = data['route']['distance'];
//$('.distance_miles').html(distance_miles);

//get formatted time
var distance_time = data['route']['formattedTime'];
$('.distance_time').html(distance_time);

}
});
```

The above code outputs :

```
"00:14:33";
```

It's fine for programmers but it's not as counter-intuitive for users.

I would like to display :

```
14 mins and 33 secs
```

In case there are hours it should display something like :

```
2 hours 14 mins and 45 secs
```

Comment: Well if you had to, you could split `"00:14:44"` into hours minutes and seconds, and go from there... `const [hours,minutes,seconds] = data['route']['formattedTime'].split(":");`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze : I will update my answer

Comment: JSON has no time format, and that's not a JavaScript Date format either.  It's just a string, with hours, minutes, and seconds (which in my opinion isn't "fine for programmers" either, as it would need to be parsed to be useful).  Seems you just need some string manipulation.

Comment: Why not have the API return the final formatted time string instead of manipulating it in JS? Presumably the backend service will be using some form of date/time object that you can output as a human readable string rather than having to fudge something at the front-end.

Answer (score 1):

This is not perfect and I am pretty sure that you can reduce the amount of code with a for sentence but this is the main idea, and of course you need to replace the string with your data.

```js
let distance_time = formatTimeString('02:10:01')
  console.log(distance_time)
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = distance_time

  function formatTimeString(time) {
    let arr = time.split(':')
    let distance_time = ''

    let hours = parseInt(arr[0])
    let minutes = parseInt(arr[1])
    let seconds = parseInt(arr[2])

    if (hours > 0 ) {
      distance_time += hours + ' hour'
      hours > 1 ? distance_time += 's ' : ' '
    }

    if (minutes > 0) {
      distance_time += minutes + ' minute'
      minutes > 1 ? distance_time += 's ' : ' '
    }

    if (seconds > 0) {
      distance_time += ' and ' + seconds + ' second'
      seconds > 1 ? distance_time += 's ' : ' '
    }

    return distance_time
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
The time you made is: <span id="time"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this help you to figure out a better way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how I missed this the first time in the docs. One quick pretty and easy way to do this is with `.replace()` or `replaceWith()`. More details [here](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

This works for me :

```
//get formatted time
var distance_time = data['route']['formattedTime'];
var distance_in_time = distance_time.replace(':',' hrs, ').replace(':',' Min and ') + ' secs.';
$('.distance_time').html(distance_in_time);
```

Comment: FYI, you can accept your own answer if you like so your question is not in the unanswered section to reduce noise.

Answer (score 0):

This will format your string correctly, as well as displaying only the relevant time suffixes. There's also a parameter for padding `0` to your digits - Your question didn't demonstrate how you wanted this behavior so I left it as a choice ( defaults to `true`)

```js
function formatTimeString(timeString, padZeros = true) {
  let arr = timeString.split(':').map(x => parseInt(x));
  let str = ['hour', 'min', 'sec'];

  return arr.reduce((acc, num, i) => {
    if (num <= 0) {
      return acc;
    } else {
      let digit = (padZeros && num < 10) ? '0' + num : num; 
      let suffix = num > 1 ? str[i] + 's' : str[i];
    
      return acc + `${digit} ${suffix} `;
    }
  }, '').replace(/(mins|min)/g, '$1 and').trim();
}

// Minutes and Seconds
console.log(formatTimeString("00:04:33", false));
console.log(formatTimeString("00:04:33", true));

// with Hours
console.log(formatTimeString("02:14:45", false));
console.log(formatTimeString("02:14:45", true));

// Just seconds
console.log(formatTimeString("00:00:50", false));
console.log(formatTimeString("00:00:50", true));
```